# Room query not working with List<String> using a type converter

Tags: sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to do a sqlite query in Room where I have a search string which can be empty or not. If empty then I want to return all the items of a specific type, otherwise I want to return any content that match the search string and that is of the specific type. The type is defined as List in my model like this:

```
@TypeConverters(DataConverter::class)
var type: List<String>? = null,
```

I wrote a query but it doesn't take the type into account and return everything containing the search query. What I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM practice 
    WHERE type LIKE '%' || 'video' || '%'
    AND (title LIKE '%' || :query || '%' 
    OR content LIKE '%' || :query || '%' 
    OR categories LIKE '%' || :query || '%' 
    OR tags LIKE '%' || :query || '%')
    ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT (:page * :pageSize)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out the problem, I was trying to match a String to a List, because with the type converter it is stored in the database as a string. But actually it is converted back to a list for the query so I changed 'video' to listOf('video') to solve the problem.